# Cronometro em JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Pessoal Fiz um cronômetro em JS mas ele "Treme" quando executo ele, existe alguma forma de arrumar isso ?

```js
var centesimas = 0;
var segundos = 0;
var minutos = 0;
var horas = 0;
function inicio () {
    control = setInterval(cronometro,10);
    document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("parar").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = false;
}
function parar () {
    clearInterval(control);
    document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = false;
}
function reinicio () {
    clearInterval(control);
    centesimas = 0;
    segundos = 0;
    minutos = 0;
    horas = 0;
    Centesimas.innerHTML = ":00";
    Segundos.innerHTML = ":00";
    Minutos.innerHTML = ":00";
    Horas.innerHTML = "00";
    document.getElementById("inicio").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("parar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("continuar").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("reinicio").disabled = true;
}
function cronometro () {
    if (centesimas < 99) {
        centesimas++;
        if (centesimas < 10) { centesimas = "0"+centesimas }
        Centesimas.innerHTML = ":"+centesimas;
    }
    if (centesimas == 99) {
        centesimas = -1;
    }
    if (centesimas == 0) {
        segundos ++;
        if (segundos < 10) { segundos = "0"+segundos }
        Segundos.innerHTML = ":"+segundos;
    }
    if (segundos == 59) {
        segundos = -1;
    }
    if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0) ) {
        minutos++;
        if (minutos < 10) { minutos = "0"+minutos }
        Minutos.innerHTML = ":"+minutos;
    }
    if (minutos == 59) {
        minutos = -1;
    }
    if ( (centesimas == 0)&&(segundos == 0)&&(minutos == 0) ) {
        horas ++;
        if (horas < 10) { horas = "0"+horas }
        Horas.innerHTML = horas;
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #ffae00;
}
.reloj{
    font-size: 170%;
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    color: #363431;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
.boton{
    margin: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    float: none;
    z-index: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 22px;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 4px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font: normal normal bold 50px/50px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -o-text-overflow: clip;
    text-overflow: clip;
    background: #FFAE00;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}
.boton:hover{
    margin: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    float: none;
    z-index: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 22px;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 4px solid rgb(255,255,255);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font: normal normal bold 50px/50px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFAE00;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -o-text-overflow: clip;
    text-overflow: clip;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
}
#crono {
    margin-top: 0%;
    width: 160%;
    margin-right: -30%;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

#numeros{
    margin-top:10%;
}

#contador{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 32%;
    left: 19%;
}
#botoes{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 120%;
    left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>cronometro</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cronometro.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cronometro.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">     </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contador">
            <div class="reloj" id="Horas">00</div>
            <div class="reloj" id="Minutos">:00</div>
            <div class="reloj" id="Segundos">:00</div>
            <div class="reloj" id="Centesimas">:00</div>
        </div>
        <div id="botoes">
            <input type="button" class="boton" id="inicio" value=" &#9658;" onclick="inicio();">
            <input type="button" class="boton" id="parar" value=" &#8718;" onclick="parar();" disabled>
            <input type="button" class="boton" id="continuar" value=" &#8634;" onclick="inicio();" disabled>
            <input type="button" class="boton" id="reinicio" value=" &#8635;" onclick="reinicio();" disabled>
        </div>
       <img id="crono" src="img/cronometro.png" alt="cronometro" title="cronometro flat">


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque a posicao do contador para relative.

```
#contador{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 32%;
    left: 19%;
}
```

a posição absolute fica fazendo o calculo a todo momento.
Referencia: o elemento com Position Absolute se utiliza do ponto superior esquerdo de outros elementos. Estes elementos são os parentes dele do elemento com position absolute. Mais especificamente o pai.

Comment: Resolveu.
Muito obrigado mesmo ajudou muito.

Comment: Marque como resposta util, na setinha ao lado pra cima. <

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.
Sou novo no fórum.

Answer (score 1):

Estou disponiblizando aqui o Cronometror, um objeto em javascript que monta um cronômetro na sua página.

1. Copie o código abaixo e salve em uma arquivo HTML
2. Abra o arquivo HTML num navegador
3. Descubra as configurações que podem ser aplicadas
4. Edite o código HTML e copie o objeto 'cronometror'
5. Cole o objeto em um arquivo javascript usando numa determinada página da sua aplicação
6. Crie um cronômetro chamando o método cronometro.criar(parametros) que retorna a referência para o cronômetro (pois você pode criar vários).
7. Informe os parâmetros desejados:

   - regressivo: tipo bool, se true o cronômetro conta de trás para frente, se false, começa do zero e vai incrementando (esse é o default)
   - segundos: tipo int, se o cronômetro for regressivo são os segundos em que o cronômetro inicia, do contário, são os segundos em que o cronômetro para (sendo que nesse caso, se for zero o cronômetro não para sozinho)
   - elemento: tipo elemento DOM (aqueles retornados com document.getElementById()), elemento onde será exibido o cronômetro
   - alertar_faltando_segundos: tipo int, se deseja que o cronômetro entre em estado de alerta quando estiverem faltando N segundos, informe aqui. O elemento do cronômetro receberá uma class chamada "alerta" e você decide o CSS dessa class.
   - iniciar: tipo bool, indica se o cronômetro já dispara assim que for criado. Para disparar depois, chamar o método cronometror.iniciar() passando como parâmetro a referência do cronômetro retornada no método cronometro.criar().
   - ao_terminar: tipo function, função javascript que é executada ao término do tempo do cronômetro. Recebe como parâmetro a referência do cronômetro encerrado.
   - funcao_para_mostrar: tipo function, função javascript que é executada para gerar a exibição do cronômetro. Recebe como parâmetros: elemento (elemento dom do cronômetro), horas, minutos, segundos (todos inteiros) e alerta (bool) que indica se o cronômetro está em estado de alerta. O próprio objeto tem dois métodos prontos de exibição e você só deve escrever seu próprio método se os que já existem não forem adequados para suas necessidades. Os métodos são: cronometror.mostraAmigavel() e cronometror.mostraPadrao(), sendo que esse é o default, ou seja, se você não informar este parâmetro na criação do cronômetro, o default será assumido.

Os métodos do objeto cronometror a serem usados são:

criar(parametros) - para criar um cronômetro, 
pausar(referencia) - para pausar um cronômetro, 
iniciar(referencia) - para iniciar um cronômetro que estiver pausado, 
zerar(referencia) - para reiniciar o tempo do cronômetro, 
destruir(referencia, destruir_elemento) - para eliminar o cronômetro, com opção para eliminar o elemento do cronômetro

```
<!doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Teste</title>
        <style>
            body
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
            }
            table
            {
                font-size: .8em;
            }
            #titulo
            {
                position: absolute;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 30px;
                line-height: 30px;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #a567aa;
                background-color: #d3bdd4;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
            }
            #formulario
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 30px;
                left: 0;
                width: 500px;
                bottom: 0;
                overflow: auto;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border-right: solid 1px lightgray;
                background-color: #e8e8e8;
            }
            #painel_cronometros
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 30px;
                left: 500px;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                overflow: auto;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .cronometro
            {
                font-size: 30px;
                padding: 10px 2px;
                background-color: #d8d8d8;
                margin: 10px 0;
                border: solid 1px #afafaf;
                border-radius: 3px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .cronometro_padrao
            {
                color: blue;
            }
            .cronometro_amigavel
            {
                color: darkgreen;
            }
            .alerta
            {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="titulo">
            TESTE DE CRONOMETRO
        </h1>
        <form id="formulario">
            <table style="margin: 20px auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0">
                <caption style="font-weight: bold; padding: 10px 0;">opções do cronômetro</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="c1">
                            segundos:
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="c1" type="number" value="10" style="width: 50px;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="c2">
                            alertar_faltando_segundos:
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="c2" type="number" value="3" style="width: 50px;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="c3">
                            regressivo:
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="c3"/> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="c4">
                            iniciar:
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="c4" checked/> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <label for="c5">
                            ao_terminar:
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="c5" style="font-style: italic;">
                            digite a função javascript
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <textarea id="c5" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;">document.getElementById('check_' + i).checked = true;</textarea> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        funcao_para_mostrar:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="f" id="c6" checked> 
                            cronometror.mostrarPadrao
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="f" id="c7"> 
                            cronometror.mostrarAmigavel
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="f" id="c8"> 
                            outro
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <label for="c9" style="font-style: italic;">
                            digite a função javascript
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <textarea id="c9" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></textarea> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="criar" onclick="criarCronometro();"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div id="painel_cronometros">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var cronometror =
            {
                instancias:
                    [],
                intervalo_milisegundos:
                    100,
                interval:
                    null,
                dados_padrao:
                    {
                        segundos: 0,
                        alertar_faltando_segundos: null,
                        regressivo: false,
                        iniciar: true,
                        ao_terminar: null,
                        elemento: null,
                        pausado: true,
                        funcao_para_mostrar: null
                    },
                criar:
                    function(dados)
                    {
                        cronometror.dados_padrao.funcao_para_mostrar = cronometror.mostraPadrao;
                        for (var i in cronometror.dados_padrao)
                        {
                            if (typeof dados[i] == 'undefined')
                            {
                                dados[i] = cronometror.dados_padrao[i];
                            }
                        }
                        dados.segundos_atuais = dados.regressivo ? dados.segundos : 0;
                        dados.segundos_iniciais = 0;
                        dados.tempo_inicio = null;
                        var i = cronometror.instancias.push(dados) - 1;
                        cronometror.mostrar(i);
                        if (dados.iniciar)
                        {
                            cronometror.iniciar(i);
                        }
                        return i;
                    },
                iniciar:
                    function(i)
                    {
                        cronometror.instancias[i].pausado = false;
                        cronometror.zerar(i);
                        cronometror.ativarIntervalo();
                    },
                ativarIntervalo:
                    function()
                    {
                        if (!cronometror.interval)
                        {
                            cronometror.interval = setInterval(cronometror.atualizar, cronometror.intervalo_milisegundos);
                        }
                    },
                pausar:
                    function(i, status)
                    {
                        status = typeof status == 'undefined' ? true : status;
                        with (cronometror.instancias[i])
                        {
                            if (status)
                            {
                                if (!pausado)
                                {
                                    cronometror.setar(i, segundos_iniciais + ((new Date() - tempo_inicio) / 1000));
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (pausado)
                                {
                                    tempo_inicio = new Date();
                                    cronometror.ativarIntervalo();
                                }
                            }
                            pausado = status;
                        }
                    },
                setar:
                    function(i, segundos)
                    {
                        cronometror.instancias[i].segundos_iniciais = segundos;
                    },
                zerar:
                    function(i)
                    {
                        with (cronometror.instancias[i])
                        {
                            tempo_inicio = new Date();
                            segundos_iniciais = 0;
                            segundos_atuais = regressivo ? segundos : 0;
                        }
                        cronometror.mostrar(i);
                    },
                destruir:
                    function(i, destruir_elemento)
                    {
                        if (typeof destruir_elemento != 'undefined' && destruir_elemento)
                        {
                            cronometror.instancias[i].elemento.parentNode.removeChild(cronometror.instancias[i].elemento);
                        }
                        delete cronometror.instancias[i];
                    },
                mostrarPadrao:
                    function(elemento, h, m, s, alerta)
                    {
                        elemento.innerHTML = 
                            '<span class="cronometro cronometro_padrao' + (alerta ? ' alerta' : '') + '">' +
                                (h < 10 ? '0' : '') + h + 
                                ':' +
                                (m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m + 
                                ':' +
                                (s < 10 ? '0' : '') + s;
                            '<span>';
                    },
                mostrarAmigavel:
                    function(elemento, h, m, s, alerta)
                    {
                        elemento.innerHTML = 
                            '<span class="cronometro cronometro_amigavel' + (alerta ? ' alerta' : '') + '">' +
                                (h ? h + 'h' : '') +
                                (m ? (h && m < 10 ? '0' : '') + m + 'm' : '') +
                                (m && s < 10 ? '0' : '') + s + 's';
                            '<span>';
                    },
                mostrar:
                    function(i)
                    {
                        var hs, ms, ss, alerta;
                        with (cronometror.instancias[i])
                        {
                            hs = (segundos_atuais / 3600) | 0;
                            ms = ((segundos_atuais - (hs * 3600)) / 60) | 0;
                            ss = segundos_atuais - (hs * 3600) - (ms * 60);
                            ss = regressivo ? Math.ceil(ss) : Math.floor(ss);
                            alerta =
                                alertar_faltando_segundos ?
                                    (
                                        regressivo ? 
                                            segundos_atuais <= alertar_faltando_segundos 
                                        : 
                                            segundos && segundos - segundos_atuais <= alertar_faltando_segundos
                                    )
                                :
                                    false;
                            funcao_para_mostrar(elemento, hs, ms, ss, alerta, i);
                        }
                    },
                atualizar:
                    function()
                    {
                        var tempo = new Date();
                        for (var i in cronometror.instancias)
                        {
                            with (cronometror.instancias[i])
                            {
                                if (pausado)
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                if (regressivo)
                                {
                                    segundos_atuais = segundos - ((tempo - tempo_inicio) / 1000) - segundos_iniciais;
                                    if (segundos_atuais <= 0)
                                    {
                                        segundos_atuais = 0;
                                        cronometror.pausar(i);
                                        if (typeof ao_terminar == 'function')
                                        {                                      
                                            ao_terminar(i);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    segundos_atuais = ((tempo - tempo_inicio) / 1000) + segundos_iniciais;
                                    if (segundos && segundos_atuais >= segundos)
                                    {
                                        segundos_atuais = segundos;
                                        cronometror.pausar(i);
                                        if (typeof ao_terminar == 'function')
                                        {
                                            ao_terminar(i);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                cronometror.mostrar(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            };
        var indice = 0;
        function criarCronometro()
        {
            var elemento = document.createElement('div');
            elemento.id = 'container_cronometro_' + indice;
            elemento.style.padding = '10px';
            elemento.style.borderBottom = 'dashed 1px ligthgray';
            elemento.innerHTML = 
                '<div style="padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: dashed 1px #aaaaaa;">' +
                    '<div>' +
                        'Cronômetro ' + indice +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="d_' + indice + '">' +
                        '<div id="cronometro_' + indice + '">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<label style="cursor: pointer">' +
                            '<input' + 
                                 ' id="check_' + indice + '"' + 
                                 ' type="checkbox"' + 
                                 ' onchange="cronometror.pausar(' + indice + ', this.checked);"' +
                                 (document.getElementById('c4').checked ? '' : ' checked') +
                            '/> ' + 
                            'pausado' + 
                        '</label>' +
                        '<span style="padding: 0 5px;">' + 
                            '|' +
                        '</span>' +
                        '<a' + 
                            ' style="cursor: pointer"' + 
                            ' onclick="cronometror.zerar(' + indice + ');"' +
                        '>' + 
                            'zerar' + 
                        '</a>' +
                        '<span style="padding: 0 5px;">' + 
                            '|' +
                        '</span>' +
                        '<a' + 
                            ' style="cursor: pointer"' + 
                            ' onclick=' + 
                                '"' + 
                                    "cronometror.destruir(" + indice + ");" + 
                                    "document.getElementById('d_" + indice + "').innerHTML = 'este cronômetro não existe mais';" + 
                                '"' + 
                        '>' + 
                            'destruir' + 
                        '</a>' +
                        '<span style="padding: 0 5px;">' + 
                            '|' +
                        '</span>' +
                        '<a' + 
                            ' style="cursor: pointer"' + 
                            ' onclick=' + 
                                '"' + 
                                    "var b = '\\n';" + 
                                    "var h = '';" + 
                                    "for (var i in cronometror.instancias[" + indice + "]) " + 
                                        "h += i + ': ' + b + String(cronometror.instancias[" + indice + "][i]) + b + b;" + 
                                    "alert(h);" + 
                                '"' + 
                        '>' + 
                            'configurações' + 
                        '</a>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            document.getElementById('painel_cronometros').appendChild(elemento);
            var parametros = 
                {
                    segundos: parseInt(document.getElementById('c1').value, 10),
                    alertar_faltando_segundos: parseInt(document.getElementById('c2').value, 10),
                    regressivo: document.getElementById('c3').checked,
                    iniciar: document.getElementById('c4').checked,
                    ao_terminar: new Function('i', document.getElementById('c5').value),
                    elemento: document.getElementById('cronometro_' + indice),
                    funcao_para_mostrar: null
                };
            if (document.getElementById('c6').checked)                             
            {
                parametros.funcao_para_mostrar = cronometror.mostrarPadrao;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('c7').checked)
            {
                parametros.funcao_para_mostrar = cronometror.mostrarAmigavel;
            }
            if (document.getElementById('c8').checked)
            {
                parametros.funcao_para_mostrar = new Function(document.getElementById('c9').value);
            }
            cronometror.criar(parametros);
            ++indice;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```