# Converter cronômetro para o formato hh mm ss

Tags: javascript, construtor, timer, setinterval, const

Meu cronômetro está correndo sem o formato 00:00:00

Criei uma div no index.html

```
<!-- TIMER -->
<div class="container">
  <span id="display">00:00:00</span>
</div>
```

No js

```
static iniciarTimer() {
        let time = 0
        const timer = document.getElementById(ID_DISPLAY)
        // atualizar o texto a cada segundo
        const atualizarTexto = () =>
        
        (timer.innerHTML =  time++)

        atualizarTexto()
        
        const idDoDisplay = setInterval(atualizarTexto, 1000)
        return idDoDisplay
    }
```

E inicio ele em outro arquivo: main usando `this.tela.iniciarTimer()`

Ele roda mas sem o padrão (00:00:00). O que devo acrescentar, retirar ou melhorar?

Comment: Precisa fazer alguns `if`s para verificar. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279563/100416) tem um exemplo

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada, e fiz esse código porém ao sair da Tela ele pausa a contagem.

Comment: Isso já seria outra pergunta. [Nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62990/100416) tem exemplos em PHP, se você quiser em JavaScript mesmo, com cache, recomendo primeiro tentar fazer e, se não conseguir, criar uma nova pergunta apresentando suas dificuldades.

Answer (score 2):

Crie um objeto do tipo [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) e com o método [`Date.prototype.setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) ajuste sua hora, minutos, segundo e milissegundos em 0. A porção respectiva a data nesse caso é irrelevante.
Dentro da sua função `atualizarTexto()` incremente em um segundo(1000 milissegundos) esse objeto do tipo `Date` com [`Date.prototype.setTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) e com o método [`Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) obtenha uma string com uma representação sensível ao idioma de uma porção de tempo dessa instancia de `Date`.

```js
function iniciarTimer() {
  const timer = document.getElementById("display");
  let time = new Date();                            //Inicializa objeto Date para ser usado como cronômetro.
  time.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);                        //Reseta o cronômetro.
  const atualizarTexto = function() {
    time.setTime(time.getTime() + 1000);            //Incrementa o cronômetro em  1s.
    timer.innerHTML = time.toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', {
      hour: "2-digit",                              //Exibirá horas.
      minute: "2-digit",                            //Exibirá minutos.
      second: "2-digit"                             //Exibirá segundos.
    });
  };
  return setInterval(atualizarTexto, 1000);
}

iniciarTimer();                                     //Inicializa o time para ser exibido aqui no exemplo.
```

```html
<!-- TIMER -->
<div class="container">
  <span id="display">00:00:00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Show! Este código está mais clean e fácil de entender. Utilizei e rodou tudo certo.

Answer (score 1):

Revendo os códigos cheguei a uma solução, deixando desta forma:

```
static cronometro () {
        let timer = document.getElementById(ID_DISPLAY)
        let timerArray = timer.textContent.split(':')
        let timerParado = true
        let [hh, mm, ss] = timerArray

        setInterval(() => {
            if(timerParado) {
                timerParado = false
            }
                ss = parseInt(ss) + 1
                timer.textContent = `${String(hh).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(mm).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(ss).padStart(2, '0')}`
            if (parseInt(ss) > 59 ) {
                ss = '00'
                mm = parseInt(mm) + 1
                timer.textContent = `${String(hh).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(mm).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(ss).padStart(2, '0')}`
            }
            else if (parseInt(mm) > 59 ) {
                mm = '00'
                hh = parseInt(hh) + 1
                timer.textContent = `${String(hh).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(mm).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(ss).padStart(2, '0')}`
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de fazer seguindo a sua linha de codigo seria, organizar o seu time em hora, minuto e segundo, e entao formatar...

```js
 function iniciarTimer() {
      let hora = 0
      let minuto = 0
      let seg = 0
      const timer = document.getElementById('display')
      // atualizar o texto a cada segundo
      const atualizarTexto = ()=>{
       timer.innerHTML = formata_numero(hora) + " : " + formata_numero(minuto) + " : " + formata_numero(seg);
          seg++; //incrementa segundos
          if (seg == 60) {
            minuto ++; //incrementa minutos a cada 60 segundos
            seg = 0;
            if (minuto == 60) {
              minuto = 0;
              hora++;//incrementa horas a cada 60 minutos
            }
          }
      }

      atualizarTexto()

      const idDoDisplay = setInterval(atualizarTexto, 1000); //set 10 para teste, porem 1000 deve ser setado para incrementar de 1 em 1 segundo
      return idDoDisplay
}
iniciarTimer();

//concatena o ZERO caso numero seja menor que 10
function formata_numero( num ){
  return (num < 10)?"0" + num:num;
}
```

```html
<!-- TIMER -->
<div class="container">
  <span id="display">00:00:00</span>
</div>
```